# Different between Text Index and Regular Index in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm wondering about the difference between Text Index and Regular Index in Mongodb. What are the specific cases where a Text Index can and a Regular Index can't?

Example: I have json with structure like this

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5f39f4a95224cf235e134c5c"
},
"name": [{
    "languageId": 228,
    "name": "A random sentence in language A"
}, {
    "languageId": 46,
    "name": "A random sentence in language B"
}],
"status": 1,
"updatedDate": {
    "$date": "2022-06-28T09:34:06.473Z"
},
"createdDate": {
    "$date": "2020-08-26T08:04:38.000Z"
}
```

}

This is my query generate by spring data mongodb:

```
{ "name.name" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : "string input", "options" : "i"}}}
```

What cases in language A can be found but not in language B when using TextIndex instead of Regular Index? Sorry for my bad Eng!

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could give us sample queries that you plan on executing? Regular indexes perform direct value comparisons whereas text indexes use techniques like tokenization and stemming to generate the keys to compare against.

Comment: @user20042973 I edited it, please take a look! Thank you!